# Create a new table on sails

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

my question is pretty simple but I can't find my answer over the web.

I'm on a project Sails/AngularJS and I simply would like to create a new table in mysql when a specific route is called.

It seems that it's not possible with waterline to create one afterwards.

I would be pleased if someone as a clue of how to resolve that.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waterline does not provide any function to create table.

### Method 1:

But it provides `Model.query()` method which you can use to perform any kind of query you want.

```
//TestController.js
module.exports = {
    action1:function(req,res){
        var queryString='CREATE TABLE if not exists sailsusers.test (id INT NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(45) NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))'
        Test.query(queryString,function(err,a){
            if(err)
              return console.log(err);
            console.log(a,'\n',b);
            res.ok();
        });
    }
};
```

So that's how you can do that!

### Method 2:(Risk of loosing data so never do in production)

in `config/models.js` add the following.

```
   migrate: 'alter'
```

whenever you lift the server one table for each model will be created automatically.But No one suggest to do that in production.

> This way is not preferred.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. When using this Model.query() I suppose it won't add me a Rest API for it ? I could execute a script call from node to execute a `sails generate API test` after that, what do you think ?

Comment: `ails generate API test` generates api only (**`api/models/Test.js` and `api/controllers/TestConteoller.js`**)